# AngularJS controller not found, for undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting AngularJS bad argument error while running the following example, please let me know where I am doing wrong ? Actually the following code is working fine if I run outside/normally, but when I copy/paste this code in my application, it is giving the following error. (this page/tab is displaying from my application's controller like: TestController, which is available in coffeescript. but I don't need any coffeescript for this requirement, I need it in AngularJs. So, In this tab, I need to display the below code/button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApplication', []);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.test = function(){
 alert("Success");
 }
}]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-app="myApplication">
  <div  ng-controller="TestController">
<div class="tab-pane" id="wizards">

<button type="button"  ng-click="test();">Test</button>

</div></div></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Error: `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=TestController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined`

Comment: added reference to your controller? example:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Controllers/AppController.js"></script>`

Comment: you are using angular 1.2.4, unless you have a good reason for this I would recommend to update to a recent version.

Comment: Whenever you're creating a new controller, be sure to make a `<script src="">` reference to it, otherwise angular *won't know where to look* for the separated controller files.

Comment: Yes, I am giving reference to it, it is loading, i can see on console Network elements, but no use.

Comment: Angular is not identifying the required controller i guess, don't know why

Comment: Got a solution, after adding the required controller in coffeescript file, it is working fine. Thanks you for your help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5KnG7RcF7QlzidR3fwWQ?p=preview) is working for me

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js">        </script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div  ng-app="myApplication">
        <div ng-controller="WizardController">
            <button ng-click="test()">Test</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Angular is not identifying the required controller, don't know why ?

Comment: Is the plunker exactly the same as your code? Can you use chrome inspector to see how is the html code generated in the browser?

Comment: Got a solution, after adding the required controller in coffeescript file, it is working fine. Thanks you for your help !!

Comment: Awesome! You can mark my post as the answer for other people :)